# Regular Expression in flex to match any word except

Tags: regex, yacc, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I have this regex in Flex to find every 2 letter capitalized word:

```
[A-Z]{2}        printf("Found %s", yytext);
```

But how can i print every word except SN ??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex will also match substrings, for example `NA` and `SA` when used on the string `NASA`.

You will need to use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to prevent that from happening. Then, use a negative [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to exclude `SN`:

```
\b(?!SN)[A-Z]{2}\b
```

**Edit:** Oh, *that* Flex :)

Well, POSIX regex engines don't know lookarounds. You'll need to spell it out:

```
\b(S[A-MO-Z]|[A-RT-Z]N|[A-MO-RT-Z]{2})\b
```

Comment: That expression gives an unrecognized rule in flex, i don't know why, i am new at this...

Comment: @JoséRicardoRibeiro: Hmm, [according to the docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=12_Using_Regular_Expressions_03.html), Flex 3 incorporates the ECMAScript regex standard set forth by ECMA-262 edition 3, and that definitely supports word boundaries and lookaheads. Which version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, its not adobe flex, its the Flex Lexical Analyzer, http://flex.sourceforge.net I should have mentioned that..